# Cannot change permalink structure of wordpress subsite

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have a Wordpress multisite install on Nginx. Currently I have site1.com as main site. And I added a new site called site2.com as subdirectory. However, I noticed you can actually click on Network Admin > Sites > Edit (site 2), you can change the domain = site2.com and path=/. Instead of using domain=site1.com and path=/site2.

I created to nginx vhost config files under sites-available. And site1 and site2 both work fine. Now you are asking me what is the problem?

The problem is with the permalinks. If you put them to /blog/%postname%/ both site1 and site2 work fine. However if you enter site2.com/blablablablaIAMFAKE the server redirects to site1.com whereas it should remain on site2 and display a 404. If you enter site2.com/blog/blablalbalbla the 404 is displayed appropriately.

One possible way to solve this is to remove the /blog from the permalinks. The tip given on the internet to change the permalink structure per site to default, and to change it under network admin >edit site> settings to /%postname%/ works fine for site1.com (the primary site). But not on site2.com.

Any ideas what could be wrong.

Thanks,

Comment: Your question it self is hard to understand, you have 2 domains? each one is hosting a wordpress? and both are on the same server, did i miss something ?

Comment: also how is `site2.com` a subdirectory?

Comment: With Apache I would use rewriting to fix that, nginix seems to do [Rewrite Rules this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html) way.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady: To answer your questions respectively: 1. Yes I have 2 domains. Both are using wordpress. Both are on the same server. I mentioned subdirectory because you've got to choose either subdirectory or subdomain when you create a new site. So I choose subdirectory when I created site2. Later I changed the site2's configuration under My Sites > Network Admin > Sites to use the site2.com domain and / as a path. Please take a look at 3.8 and you will see it. I didn't have to use any plugins to domain map!

Comment: so site2 lives inside a subfolder of site1 right ? but each has it's own domain, can't you move it to a sibling folder? would be cleaner.

Comment: Site2 is using a theme inside themes folder. Just like site1. None is inside the other. The network was setup using subfolders as a choice. Other than that, they are pretty much separated. Each one has its domain, its theme, and its tables though they share the same db schema.